# DDD Service Method Granularity

Tags: domain-driven-design

So, I'm building a system for managing contacts.  My contact domain model has quite a few string properties, as well as booleans.  In the spirit of keeping behavior inside of the domain models, I've gone down the path of creating "update methods."  I'm starting to feel like it's getting a bit burdensome.  In the past, CRUD apps would just have a single update method and it would set all of the properties in one shot.

Am I on the right path?  I'm concerned about having 10 - 15 update methods on my domain service and domain entities.

FYI, the example given is a bit contrived, so imagine a model with lots of string and boolean properties.

```
 // Application Layer Stuff
 public class UpdateContactCommand
 {
      public UpdateNamePredicate UpdateName { get; set; }
      public UpdatePhonePredicate UpdatePhone { get; set; }
      public int ContactId { get; set; }
 }

 public class UpdateNamePredicate
 {
      public string NewFirstName { get; set; }
      public string NewLastName { get; set; }
 }
 public class UpdatePhonePredicate
 {
      public string NewPHone { get; set; }

 }

 public class UpdateContactResponse
 {
      public bool Success { get; set; }
      public string Message { get; set; }
 }

 public interface IWcfService
 {
      UpdateContactResponse UpdateContact(UpdateContactCommand updateContactCommand);
 }

 public class WcfService : IWcfService
 {
      private readonly IContactService _contactService;

      public WcfService(IContactService contactService)
      {
           _contactService = contactService;
      }

      public UpdateContactResponse UpdateContact(UpdateContactCommand updateContactCommand)
      {
           if (updateContactCommand.UpdateName != null)
           {
                _contactService.UpdateName(updateContactCommand.ContactId, updateContactCommand.UpdateName.NewFirstName,
                     updateContactCommand.UpdateName.NewLastName);
           }

           if (updateContactCommand.UpdatePhone != null)
           {
                _contactService.UpdatePhone(updateContactCommand.ContactId, updateContactCommand.UpdatePhone.NewPHone);
           }

           return new UpdateContactResponse();
      }
 }



 // Domain Layer
 public interface IContactService
 {
      // There are lots more of these
      void UpdateName(int contactId, string newFirstName, string newLastName);
      void UpdatePhone(int contactId, string newPhone);
 }


 public class ContactService : IContactService
 {
      private readonly IContactRepository _contactRepository;

      public ContactService(IContactRepository contactRepository)
      {
           _contactRepository = contactRepository;
      }

      public void UpdateName(int contactId, string newFirstName, string newLastName)
      {
           var contact = _contactRepository.GetById(contactId);

           contact.SetName(newFirstName, newLastName);

           _contactRepository.Commit();
      }

      public void UpdatePhone(int contactId, string newPhone)
      {
           var contact = _contactRepository.GetById(contactId);

           contact.SetPhone(newPhone);

           _contactRepository.Commit();
      }
 }

 public interface IContact
 {
      int Id { get; set; }

     // There are lots more of these
      void SetName(string newFirstName, string newLastName);
      void SetPhone(string newPhone);
 }

 public class Contact : IContact
 {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string FirstName { get; set; }
      public string LastName { get; set; }
      public string Phone { get; set; }
      public void SetName(string newFirstName, string newLastName)
      {
           FirstName = newFirstName;
           LastName = newLastName;
      }

      public void SetPhone(string newPhone)
      {
           Phone = newPhone;
      }
 }

 public interface IContactRepository
 {
      IContact GetById(int id);
      void Commit();
 }

 public class ContactRepository : IContactRepository
 {
      public IContact GetById(int id)
      {
           // Not important
           throw new NotImplementedException();
      }

      public void Commit()
      {
          // Not important
           throw new NotImplementedException();
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, not all applications lend themselves well to a DDD approach. If you say your application could pretty much have been implemented in a CRUDish way before, chances are it's still CRUD now. Don't try to apply DDD on any app because it's the shiny new thing.

That being said, you don't just write "update methods" for the fun of it. They have to reflect the domain [tasks](http://kylecordes.com/2014/task-based-user-interfaces) your user wants to perform. Why does the user want to update a Contact ? Has the contact moved or just changed phone number ? Changed marital status and name ? Has the point of contact in a company been taken over by another employee ?

Usually, you won't have tons of update methods for a given entity. There's always a way to group changes in operations that are meaningful for the domain. Good ways to force yourself to do it are :

- Think about the maximum number of form fields you can reasonably display to the user. Couldn't you split that complex UI into smaller, more meaningful screens ? From there you have to start reasoning (preferably with the help of a domain expert) about the tasks these should reflect.
- Make [your entity fields](http://www.jefclaes.be/2013/04/designing-entities-immutability-first.html) [immutable](http://blog.gauffin.org/2012/06/protect-your-data/) from the outside. Thus you'll have to think harder about their true nature -- what should be in the constructor ? what should some other manipulation methods be ?